# Marshal a Record to JSON and back

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I would like to serialize a complex record (it contains a couple levels of dynamic arrays with subrecords) to a JSON string, and back, from a JSON string get the record it represents.

Normally I would use the TJSONMarshal and TJSONUnMarshal classes, but TJSONMarshal.Marshal doesn't accept records, only objects. Do you know of an alternative that can be used with records ?.

Thank you.

Comment: Synopse mORMot Framework, UNIT SynCommons, FUNCTION RecordSaveJSON

Comment: @PeterWolf Thanks Peter, yes it also works directly on records.

Comment: @HeartWare Thank you, I have gone with Peter's suggestion because Superobject seems to be a much lighter module.